# How to extend/inherit form_view.js in Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

Am using Odoo10 customized in file web\static\src\js\views\form_view.js in below method:

form_view.js

```
odoo.define('web.FormRenderingEngine', function (require) {
   "use strict";
   process_group: function($group) {
          // custom Code
  }
});
```

Am extending this file like as mention below:

```
var FormRenderingEngine = require('web.FormRenderingEngine');
return FormRenderingEngine.extend({
   process_group: function($group) {   // custom Code
}
}};
```

.extend or include doesn't work.

please anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any kind of error you are getting then show that error because '**.extend**' as well as '**.include**' both works here. Yes, syntax is different for both. I am giving you reference:

1) Using '**.extend**'

```
var FormRenderingEngine = require('web.FormRenderingEngine');
return FormRenderingEngine.extend({
  custome_function_name : function(){
      //code
  },
});
```

2) Using '**.include**'

```
var config = require('web.config');
var core = require('web.core');
var FormRenderingEngine = require('web.FormRenderingEngine');
var _t = core._t;

FormRenderingEngine.include({
function_name: function(){
//code
},
```

});